# How can I factor the polynomial $x^7-1$ in GF(2)?

Tags: factoring, coding-theory, cyclotomic-polynomials

The result is $(x+1)(x^3+x+1)(x^3+x^2+1)$, but I don't understand how I can calculate it.

Comment: The irreducible polynomials of degree $2$ and $3$ over $\mathbf{F}_2$ are known, and there is not very many of them, so you can just trial divide.

Comment: ... not to mention degree 1.

Comment: And you can even speed *that* up by recognizing that the roots are the nonzero elements of $\mathbf{F}_8$.

Comment: Question is wrong. Because if we expand $(x+1)(x^3+x+1)(x^3+x^2+1)$ we don't get $x^7-1$

Comment: @Soheil:  we do over $GF_2$ because $0=2$ and $+1=-1$

Comment: Sorry, My bad...

Answer (score 1):

In the reals, $x^7-1=(x-1)(x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)$, so that is true in $GF(2)$ as well.  Then $x-1=x+1$  Now we have to factor the second term.  The degrees of the factors need to add to $6$ and both factors must include $+1$.  That doesn't leave many to try.  If we guess that we have two cubics, we have $(x^3+?x^2+?x+1)(x^3+?x^2+?x+1)=x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$  To get the $x^5$ term we need one of the squares to be $1$ and the other zero, so we have $(x^3+x^2+?x+1)(x^3+?x+1)=x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1.$ To get the $x$ term one of the linear factors must be $1$ and the other zero-leaving two possibilities.

Comment: If $x^6+x^5+\cdots+x+1$ factors into two irreducible cubics $g(x)$ and $h(x)$, then these cubics must be _self-reciprocal_ ($g(x) = x^3g(x^{-1})$ and $h(x)=x^3h(x^{-1})$, or reciprocals of each other: $g(x)=x^3h(x^{-1})$. The first case does not work because $x^3+x^2+x+1$ and $x^3+1$ both have $1$ as a root and so are reducible. So the second case must be the truth and we get immediately that the factors are the reciprocal polynomials $x^3+x^2+1$ and $x^3+x+1$.

Answer (score 0):

It easy to see that 1 is the only root of $x^7-1$ in $GF(2)$. So $x^7-1=(x-1)(x^6+x^5+\cdots +1)$.
Now suppose $f=x^6+\cdots+1$ is reducible. Let $f_1$ be a irreducible factor of $f$ with minimal degree. Then $deg(f_1)=2$ or $3$. But it is easy to find all the irreducible polynomials of degree $\le 3$(hint: polynomial $g$ such that $2\le deg(g) \le 3$ is irreducible if and only $g$ has a root.)